# Hospital appointments registry

Tags: c++, object-oriented

```
#ifndef REGISTRY_REGISTRY_H
#define REGISTRY_REGISTRY_H

#include <vector>
#include "patient.h"
#include "doctor.h"
#include "appointment.h"

class Registry {

public:

    Registry();

    ~Registry();

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Patient>> GetPatients() const;

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Doctor>> GetDoctors() const;

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Appointment>> GetAppointments() const;

    void SetPatients(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Patient>> patients);

    void SetDoctors(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Doctor>> doctors);

    void SetAppointments(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Appointment>> appointments);

    void Add(Doctor doctor);

    void Add(Patient patient);

    void Add(DoctorID doctorId, PatientID patientId, Date date);

    void Remove(PatientID id);

    void Remove(DoctorID id);

    void Remove(AppointmentID id);

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Appointment>> FindAppointments(DoctorID id);

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Appointment>> FindAppointments(PatientID id);

    void ShowAll(const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Patient>> &patients) const;

    void ShowAll(const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Doctor>> &doctors) const;

    void
    ShowAll(const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Appointment>> &appointments,
            const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Patient>> &patients) const;

    void
    ShowAll(const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Appointment>> &appointments,
            const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Doctor>> &doctors) const;


    void ShowAll(const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Appointment>> &appointments,
                 const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Patient>> &patients,
                 const std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Doctor>> &doctors) const;

private:

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Patient>> patients_;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Doctor>> doctors_;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Appointment>> appointments_;

    void Remove(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Doctor>>::iterator itDoctor);

    void Remove(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Patient>>::iterator itPatient);

    void Remove(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Appointment>>::iterator itAppointment);

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Patient>>::iterator Find(PatientID id);

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Doctor>>::iterator Find(DoctorID id);

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Appointment>>::iterator Find(AppointmentID id);

};

#endif //REGISTRY_REGISTRY_H
```

```
#include "../include/registry.h"
#include "../include/idgenerator.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Registry::Registry() {

}

Registry::~Registry() {

}

vector<pair<string, Patient>> Registry::GetPatients() const {

    return patients_;
}

vector<pair<string, Doctor>> Registry::GetDoctors() const {

    return doctors_;
}

vector<pair<string, Appointment>> Registry::GetAppointments() const {

    return appointments_;
}

void Registry::SetPatients(vector<pair<string, Patient>> patients) {

    patients_ = patients;
}

void Registry::SetDoctors(vector<pair<string, Doctor>> doctors) {

    doctors_ = doctors;
}

void Registry::SetAppointments(vector<pair<string, Appointment>> appointments) {

    appointments_ = appointments;
}


void Registry::Add(Doctor doctor) {

    doctors_.emplace_back(IdGenerator::Generate(), doctor);
}

void Registry::Add(Patient patient) {

    patients_.emplace_back(IdGenerator::Generate(), patient);
}

void Registry::Add(DoctorID doctorId, PatientID patientId, Date date) {

    auto itDoctor = Find(doctorId);

    if (itDoctor == doctors_.end()) {

        throw invalid_argument("Лікаря з таким кодом не існує");
    }

    auto itPatient = Find(patientId);

    if (itPatient == patients_.end()) {

        throw invalid_argument("Пацієнта з таким кодом не існує");
    }

    Appointment newAppointment(itPatient->first, itDoctor->first, date);

    // emplace_back - вместо того, чтобы принимать value_type, он принимает вариативный список аргументов, так что это означает,
    // что теперь вы можете идеально пересылать аргументы и напрямую создавать объект в контейнере без временного хранения.
    appointments_.emplace_back(IdGenerator::Generate(), newAppointment);
}


void Registry::Remove(PatientID id) {

    auto it = Find(id);

    if (it == patients_.end()) {

        throw invalid_argument("Пацієнта з таким кодом не існує");
    }

    Remove(it);

}

void Registry::Remove(DoctorID id) {

    auto it = Find(id);

    if (it == doctors_.end()) {

        throw invalid_argument("Лікаря з таким кодом не існує");
    }

    Remove(it);
}

void Registry::Remove(AppointmentID id) {

    auto it = Find(id);

    if (it == appointments_.end()) {

        throw invalid_argument("Прийому пацієнта до лікаря з таким кодом не існує");
    }

    Remove(it);
}


vector<pair<string, Appointment>> Registry::FindAppointments(DoctorID id) {

    auto it = Find(id);

    if (it == doctors_.end()) {

        throw invalid_argument("Лікаря з таким кодом не існує");
    }

    vector<pair<string, Appointment>> doctorAppointments;
    string doctorKey = it->first;

    copy_if(appointments_.begin(), appointments_.end(), back_inserter(doctorAppointments),
            [&doctorKey](const pair<string, Appointment> &appointment) {

                return appointment.second.GetDoctorKey() == doctorKey;
            });

    return doctorAppointments;
}

vector<pair<string, Appointment>> Registry::FindAppointments(PatientID id) {

    auto it = Find(id);

    if (it == patients_.end()) {

        throw invalid_argument("Пацієнта з таким кодом не існує");
    }

    vector<pair<string, Appointment>> patientAppointments;
    string patientKey = it->first;

    copy_if(appointments_.begin(), appointments_.end(), back_inserter(patientAppointments),
            [&patientKey](const pair<string, Appointment> &appointment) {

                return appointment.second.GetPatientKey() == patientKey;
            });


    return patientAppointments;
}


void Registry::Remove(vector<pair<string, Patient>>::iterator itPatient) {

    string patientKey = itPatient->first;
    patients_.erase(itPatient);

    // Удаляю все приемы в которых удаленный пациент
    // erase - удаляет из вектора один элемент (позицию), либо диапазон элементов.
    appointments_.erase(

            // remove_if - элементы удовлетворяющие условию записывает в конец вектора, и возвращает итератор на начало элементов на удаление
            remove_if(appointments_.begin(), appointments_.end(),
                      [&patientKey](const pair<string, Appointment> &appointment) {

                          return appointment.second.GetPatientKey() == patientKey;

                      }), appointments_.end());

}

void Registry::Remove(vector<pair<string, Doctor>>::iterator itDoctor) {

    string doctorKey = itDoctor->first;
    doctors_.erase(itDoctor);

    appointments_.erase(

            remove_if(appointments_.begin(), appointments_.end(),
                      [&doctorKey](const pair<string, Appointment> &appointment) {

                          return appointment.second.GetDoctorKey() == doctorKey;

                      }), appointments_.end());

}

void Registry::Remove(vector<pair<string, Appointment>>::iterator itAppointment) {

    appointments_.erase(itAppointment);
}

vector<pair<string, Patient>>::iterator Registry::Find(PatientID id) {

    // find_if - возвращает итератор к первому элементу в диапазоне [first, last], для которого предикат возвращает true.
    // Если такой элемент не найден, функция возвращает last.

    auto it = find_if(patients_.begin(), patients_.end(),
                      [&id](const pair<string, Patient> &patient) {

                          return patient.second.GetID() == id;
                      });

    return it;
}

vector<pair<string, Doctor>>::iterator Registry::Find(DoctorID id) {

    auto it = find_if(doctors_.begin(), doctors_.end(),
                      [&id](const pair<string, Doctor> &doctor) {

                          return doctor.second.GetID() == id;
                      });

    return it;
}

vector<pair<string, Appointment>>::iterator Registry::Find(AppointmentID id) {

    auto it = find_if(appointments_.begin(), appointments_.end(),
                      [&id](const pair<string, Appointment> &appointment) {

                          return appointment.second.GetID() == id;
                      });

    return it;
}

void Registry::ShowAll(const vector<pair<string, Patient>> &patients) const {

    for (int i = 0; i < patients.size(); i++) {

        patients[i].second.Show();
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Registry::ShowAll(const vector<pair<string, Doctor>> &doctors) const {

    for (int i = 0; i < doctors.size(); i++) {

        doctors[i].second.Show();
        cout << endl;

    }
}

void Registry::ShowAll(const vector<pair<string, Appointment>> &appointments,
                       const vector<pair<string, Patient>> &patients) const {


    for (int i = 0; i < appointments.size(); i++) {

        cout << endl;
        AppointmentID appointmentId = appointments[i].second.GetID();
        cout << "Номер прийому: " << appointmentId << endl << endl;

        string patientKey = appointments[i].second.GetPatientKey();

        auto patientIt = find_if(patients.begin(), patients.end(), [&patientKey](const pair<string, Patient> &patient) {

            return patient.first == patientKey;
        });

        patientIt->second.Show();

        cout << endl;

        Date date = appointments[i].second.GetDate();
        cout << "Дата прийому: ";
        date.Show();
        cout << endl;

    }

}

void Registry::ShowAll(const vector<pair<string, Appointment>> &appointments,
                       const vector<pair<string, Doctor>> &doctors) const {

    for (int i = 0; i < appointments.size(); i++) {

        cout << endl;
        AppointmentID appointmentId = appointments[i].second.GetID();
        cout << "Номер прийому: " << appointmentId << endl << endl;

        string doctorKey = appointments[i].second.GetDoctorKey();

        auto doctorIt = find_if(doctors.begin(), doctors.end(), [&doctorKey](const pair<string, Doctor> &doctor) {

            return doctor.first == doctorKey;
        });

        doctorIt->second.Show();

        cout << endl;

        Date date = appointments[i].second.GetDate();
        cout << "Дата прийому: ";
        date.Show();
        cout << endl;

    }
}


void Registry::ShowAll(const vector<pair<string, Appointment>> &appointments,
                       const vector<pair<string, Patient>> &patients,
                       const vector<pair<string, Doctor>> &doctors) const {

    for (int i = 0; i < appointments.size(); i++) {

        cout << endl;
        AppointmentID appointmentId = appointments[i].second.GetID();
        cout << "Номер прийому: " << appointmentId << endl << endl;

        string patientKey = appointments[i].second.GetPatientKey();

        auto patientIt = find_if(patients.begin(), patients.end(), [&patientKey](const pair<string, Patient> &patient) {

            return patient.first == patientKey;
        });

        patientIt->second.Show();

        cout << endl;
        string doctorKey = appointments[i].second.GetDoctorKey();

        auto doctorIt = find_if(doctors.begin(), doctors.end(), [&doctorKey](const pair<string, Doctor> &doctor) {

            return doctor.first == doctorKey;

        });

        doctorIt->second.Show();

        Date date = appointments[i].second.GetDate();
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Дата прийому: ";
        date.Show();
        cout << endl;

    }
}
```

Hi all, I want to implement a hospital Registry class. But I don't know how to do it properly.

It should contain vectors of patients, doctors and appointments of patients to doctors.

It should have functionality to add, delete patients, doctors and appointments of patients to doctors, etc. For correct deletion of objects, there should be a search method for these objects.

I also want to make a functionality, for example, to search for patients' appointments with certain doctors.

Objects, for example Patient has structure field PatientID and these IDs are generated in constructor at object creation and have number form (0, 1, 2...). I did it as a structure to do overloading in Remove() methods for example.

In class, I plan to store objects in pairs, the first element of the pair - string (object key, something like UUID), the second element of the pair - the object itself. These keys will be generated in Add() methods. I can not use ID objects which are generated in object constructors, because after restarting the program they can be different each time, and it's not allowed to bind patients and doctors in Appointment object, so I plan to keep patient and doctor keys in Appointment objects for binding them, because the keys are generated only once and never change.

I think that my implementation is not very good, because right now it's just focused on object IDs, but what if I want to search for objects by name? I don't know how to make overloaded methods in this case. What are your recommendations? What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Can you confirm that the code is complete and that it functions correctly? If so, I recommend that you [edit] to add a summary of the testing (ideally, show the unit-tests that we can all run).  If it's not working, it isn't ready for review (see [help/on-topic]) and the question may be deleted.

Comment: I don't have unit tests, it's just my homework. I run it on my computer and it works.

Comment: _How_ did you run it?  There's no `main()` function.

Comment: In fact, I can't even compile it because it references headers that aren't in standard C++.

Comment: The whole program consist of about 10+ classes, i'm just asking about one of them. These headers are my classes of patients, doctors, etc.

Comment: It's harder to review code we can't compile and run for ourselves.  So that will likely reduce the attention this question gets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`using namespace std;` can lead to surprises when standard library functions (including template functions) better match that the functions we think we're calling.  Namespaces exist to help us separate similar-named functions and throwing that away by pulling the entirety of `std` into the global namespace is quite harmful.

If you really feel unable to use the five characters `std::`, then consider importing *specific* names into the global namespace - even then, I'd advise keeping their scope small (at least you didn't do it in the header, where it would harm every program using it!).

---

It's not clear why we have so many vectors of pairs - most of those look like they would be better as `std::map` objects, especially as we have written a lot of linear searches over them.

---

I'm surprised you need six overloads of `Remove()` - the private ones are called once each, so just inline those at their call sites.

You could make `Remove()` and `FindAppointments()` much simpler (and faster) by maintaining back-references from each doctor and patient to their appointment objects (probably as a collection of `std::reference_wrapper` objects).  You'll need to make sure these are updated correctly when appointments are changed (added, modified or deleted) of course.

---

There's a lot of searching that matches on the `second` element of a pair, using `std::find_if`.  We could write a convenience function to generate all those similar functors:

```
auto match_id(auto const& id)
{
    return [&id](auto const& pair){ return pair.second.GetID == id; };
}
```

So we could write

```
auto Registry::Find(const PatientID& id)
{
    return std::ranges::find_if(patients_, match_id(id));
}
```

and similar.  But it might be more productive to consider supplying a *projection* argument to the `find` algorithm, and avoid the need for a predicate function.  E.g.

```
auto Registry::Find(const PatientID& id)
{
    using PatientPair = std::pair<std::string, Patient>;
    return std::ranges::find(patients, id, &PatientPair::second);
}
```